# React-Native-firebase Push notifications(android) doesnt display the 'body' of the request on the background or when app is closed

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, react-native, firebase-notifications

Notifications work great on the foreground , I get both the console.log and the action to navigate .

On the background They get displayed ,I get the console.log and action to navigate when I press to open them , but this time the body of my notification is undefined.I can only see the 'data' that I set from the firebase console and Not the message and the Title.

When the App is closed and I press the notification , The app opens but I dont get the console.log or the navigate to next page action.

```
 import DetailPage from './Detail';
 import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

 import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

import { registerAppListener } from "./Listeners";
import firebaseClient from "./FirebaseClient";

class MainPage extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        token: ""
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
        'test',
        'Channel Name',
        firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
      ).setDescription('A natural description of the channel');
     firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    this.unsubscribeFromNotificationListener = 
      firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {


            const localNotification = new 
       firebase.notifications.Notification({
                sound: 'default',
                show_in_foreground: true,
            })
                .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
                .setTitle(notification.title)
                .setSubtitle(notification.subtitle)
                .setBody(notification.body)
                .setData(notification.data)
                .android.setChannelId('test') // e.g. the id you chose above
                .android.setSmallIcon('ic_stat_notification') // create this 
               icon in Android Studio
                .android.setColor('#000000') // you can set a color here

          .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

            firebase.notifications()
                .displayNotification(localNotification)
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
            console.log(localNotification)
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')
            }, 500)


    registerAppListener(this.props.navigation);
    firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()
        .then((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
            if (notificationOpen) {
                // Get information about the notification that was opened
                const notif: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
                console.log('foo');
                console.log(notif);
                this.setState({
                    initNotif: notif.data
                })
                if (notif && notif.targetScreen === 'detail') {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')
                    }, 500)
                }
            }
        });

    if (!await firebase.messaging().hasPermission()) {
        try {
            await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Failed to grant permission")
        }
    }

    firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token => {
        console.log("TOKEN (getFCMToken)", token);
        this.setState({ token: token || "" })

    });

    // topic example
    firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic('news');
    //firebase.messaging().unsubscribeFromTopic('sometopic');

    var offline = await AsyncStorage.getItem('headless')
    if (offline) {
        this.setState({
            offlineNotif: offline
        });
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('headless');
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onTokenRefreshListener();
    this.notificationOpenedListener();
    this.messageListener();
    this.unsubscribeFromNotificationListener();
    this.registerAppListener();

}

showLocalNotification() {
    let notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification();
    notification = notification.setNotificationId(new 
 Date().valueOf().toString())
        .setTitle("Test")
        .setBody("Force touch to reply")
        .setSound("bell.mp3")
        .setData({
            now: new Date().toISOString()
        });
    notification.ios.badge = 10
    notification.android.setAutoCancel(true);

    notification.android.setBigPicture("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png", "https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/small-boy-cartoon_318-38077.jpg", "content title", "summary text")
    notification.android.setColor("red")
    notification.android.setColorized(true)
    notification.android.setOngoing(true)
    notification.android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
    notification.android.setSmallIcon("ic_launcher")
    notification.android.setVibrate([300])
    notification.android.addAction(new firebase.notifications.Android.Action("view", "ic_launcher", "VIEW"))
    notification.android.addAction(new firebase.notifications.Android.Action("reply", "ic_launcher", "REPLY").addRemoteInput(new firebase.notifications.Android.RemoteInput("input")))
    notification.android.setChannelId("test")

    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification)
}




Listener.js 

 function displayNotificationFromCustomData(message: RemoteMessage){
 if(message.data && message.data.title){
 let notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification();
  notification = notification
  .setTitle(message.data.title)
  .setBody(message.data.body)
  .setData(message.data)
  .setSound("bell.mp3")


notification.android
.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
  notification.android.setChannelId("test")
firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
console.log(notification);
console.log('received');
}
}

export async function registerHeadlessListener(message: RemoteMessage){
await AsyncStorage.setItem('headless', new Date().toISOString());
displayNotificationFromCustomData(message);
 }

// these callback will be triggered only when app is foreground or 
 background
 export function registerAppListener(navigation){
 this.notificationListener = 
 firebase.notifications().onNotification(notification => {
 firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
})
this.notificationOpenedListener = 
firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: 
NotificationOpen) => {
const notif: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
console.log(notif);
 console.log('works');
// if(notif.data.targetScreen === 'detail'){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    navigation.navigate('Detail')
  }, 500)
//}
// setTimeout(()=>{
//   alert(`User tapped notification\n${notif.notificationId}`)
// }, 500)
});

this.onTokenRefreshListener = firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh(token => {
console.log("TOKEN (refreshUnsubscribe)", token);
});

 this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message: 
RemoteMessage) 
=> {
 displayNotificationFromCustomData(message);
});

}
```

and my AndroidManifest :

```
   <service android:name="io.invertase
   .firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
         </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service 
 android:name="io.invertase
.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase
 .firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
```

Comment: On a first look it seems to be the right code. Could you please log notification.body?

Comment: I am using react native debugger and I can see the notification.body is undefined, I am not really sure how the notification.data is displayed perfectly but the body is undefined

Comment: Update to my current issue: I noticed a yellow warning telling me I need to set the channel ID.I define the chanel ID in the firebase console as 'test' which is the same name as the chanel I defined in my hardcoded Chanel.Any ideas ?

Comment: Ensure you are subscribing to topic as soon as the app start and getInitialNotification is called always on componentDidMount and not inside the onNotification. Ensure that your AndroidManifest has all the requested tags (like the one for RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver that I cannot see here)

Comment: I checked all of the above ,I am almost sure it has something to do with me NOT setting corectly the notification chanel-ID since the only thing not working is displaying the body of the background notification . IF the code above is correct then Could it be I am not seting the ChanelID from the firebase console correctly?

Comment: Yes, even if it is a bit strange. Try to uninstall the app and try to use a channel id equal to the channel name. Don't use spaces (use for example "app-channel") for channel id and name both.